# How to execute custom cloud function on Stripe-Firebase extension's events

Tags: firebase, stripe-payments

I just setup Firebase Stripe Extension for my Web App. Everything goes fine. But I am struggling to add few custom functionality. I want to add some token balance for every successful subscription.

E.g.

5USD / Month - 2000 Token
19 USD/ Month - 50000 Token

And these token should be used to call an external API.

I think I can use Eventarc for that. But I don't find any documentation for that. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: One possibility is to adapt the open-source code of the extension and deploy it yourself. See https://github.com/stripe/stripe-firebase-extensions

Comment: I found the extension publishes events. Would you please have a look https://github.com/stripe/stripe-firebase-extensions/issues/507

Comment: Hey, I'm working on the same thing, do you find something? I'm a little stuck with eventarc and all these things :)

Comment: Same issue here!